# Default IPv6 route keeps disappearing

Tags: ubuntu, networking, ipv6

I've got an dedicated server hosted by [KimSufi](https://kimsufi.com/) that's running *Ubuntu Server 18.04*. While I've goto both an IPv4 address and an IPv6 address, I keep getting random dropouts on IPv6. Doing a `ping -6 google.com` when it's dropped out yields this:

```
Network is unreachable
```

If I try sudo ifup eth0`, then I get this:

RTNETLINK answers: File exists
   Failed to bring up eth0.

...as the interface is already up - just IPv4 only. By executing `ifup -n eth0` however, I can see a list of commands it executes when bringing the interface up. In particular, executing the following command appears to fix the issue temporarily:

```
/sbin/ip -family inet6 route add default via 2001:41d0:e:07ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

....then (after a bit of a delay), testing via `ping -6 google.com` works again.

However, it drops out again randomly soon after.

**Does anyone know what's going on, and how I can stop the default IPv6 route from disappearing?**

**Edit:** The IPv6 section of `/etc/network/interfaces` looks like this:

```
iface eth0 inet6 static
    address 2001:41d0:e:074b::1
    netmask 128
    dns-nameservers 2001:41d0:3:163::1
    post-up /sbin/ip -family inet6 route add 2001:41d0:e:07ff:ff:ff:ff:ff dev eth0
    post-up /sbin/ip -family inet6 route add default via 2001:41d0:e:07ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    pre-down /sbin/ip -family inet6 route del default via 2001:41d0:e:07ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    pre-down /sbin/ip -family inet6 route del 2001:41d0:e:07ff:ff:ff:ff:ff dev eth0
```

Comment: I assume you get your IPv6 address information via DHCP? I would guess your provider has some issues with IPv6 which causes it to not advertise the default route anymore. IPv6 uses router advertisement messages to provide address information such as the IPv6 address and gateway information.

Comment: Kimsufi requires manual configuration for IPv6 (and IPv4). How have you configured networking?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Ah, right! I've added the relevant section of `/etc/network/interfaces` to the bottom of my answer.

Comment: Hm, your prefix should be 64 and not 128, but I'm not certain that's the cause of this problem. Might be the cause of other problems, though.

Comment: I agree that the prefix is not right, but I'm not sure that it should be a /64. If that gateway address is correct, it doesn't even reside in the /64 of the interface. The interface would actually need to be a /56, which would give the network a range from `2001:41d0:e:700:0:0:0:0` to `2001:41d0:e:7ff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff`.

Comment: Sounds like it might be worth contacting my hosting provider to obtain the correct settings, @guzzijason?

Comment: @guzzijason I checked an OVH server I have access to. /64 is correct, not /56 or /128. They intentionally have the gateway outside the subnet, so you have to have a static route to it as well.

Comment: This just seems bizarre to me, even if it works. Not having a default gateway which is reachable directly sort of defeats the purpose of having a default gateway. If you don't have a gateway address that's part of your "public" IPv6 interface's network, then I would much rather use the link-local address (in the fe80::/10 prefix), as it is guaranteed to exist. Note, however, that if you do use the link-local as your default gateway, you do need to specify a local interface for that route, such as: `ip -6 route add default via fe80::21c:73ff:fe00:a0 dev eth0`

Comment: @guzzijason I don't understand why you would specify the link-local as the default gateway? Would all the traffic never leave the server in that case? Also, How do I set the prefix? Is that with the `netmask` property in `/etc/network/interfaces`?

Comment: No, don't use the link-local address of the server, use the link-local address of the router. Every IPv6 interface has a link-local address automatically. You just need to figure out what it is. You should be able to see it in the IPv6 neighbor table (`ip -6 neighbor show`) or by pinging the all-routers IPv6 multicast address (`ping6 ff02::2%eth0`) and see who responds. Note, however that every time you are working with a link-local address - whether adding a route, or doing a ping as I suggest here, you must include an interface name as well, otherwise it will error.

Comment: If I do the `ip -6 neighbor show` command, I see this: https://pastebin.com/raw/YtXpe45U
The `ping6 ff02::2%eth0` command times out. What should I change then, and how is the related to my issue of IPv6 dropping out randomly, @guzzijason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on comments provided so far, I would try replacing the routing on the interface config with the following:

```
post-up /sbin/ip -family inet6 route add default via fe80::1ee6:c7ff:fe52:740 dev eth0
pre-down /sbin/ip -family inet6 route del default via fe80::1ee6:c7ff:fe52:740 dev eth0
```

... and see if that has any affect on the reliabiltiy of the default route.

Comment: Going to wait a week before accepting this as the answer to see if it works.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what do you have for `net.ipv6.conf.eth0.accept_ra` or `net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra`? If it's 1 and your network is not broadcasting router advertisements, even though you set eth0 to statically configure, it may be dropping the default route when it never receives advertisements.

Comment: Hey, @cburn11 Both of those properties are indeed set to `1`. What can I do about this? Would setting them to `0` help? How can I do this such that it persists across reboots?

Also, great solution @guzzijason, but it's still dropping out :-/

Comment: If you set it to 0 at least you know it's not ifupdown that is clearing your default route. To make it persist you could include: "net.ipv6.conf.eth0.accept_ra=0" and "net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra=0" in /etc/sysctl.com and the run "sudo sysctl -p" or you could add "pre-up echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/accept_ra" and  "pre-up echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/eth0/accept_ra" to /etc/network/interfaces